# Що таке "спетлювать" у "Ой чи є, чи нема Пан господар дома?"

Tags: значення-слів

Що означає *спетлювать* у цій щедрівці?

> Ой чи є, чи нема
> Пан господар вдома?
> Щедрий вечір, добрий вечір,
> Пан господар вдома.
>
> Ой нема, ой нема –
> Та й поїхав до млина.
> Щедрий вечір, добрий вечір,
> Та й поїхав до млина.
>
> Пшениченьки **спетлювать**,
> Меду-пива купувать.
> Щедрий вечір, добрий вечір,
> Меду-пива купувать.
>
> Меду-пива купувать,
> Свої гості частувать.
> Щедрий вечір, добрий вечір,
> Свої гості частувать.
> <sub>Мелодія народна, текст і гармонізація Леопольда Ященка. Хор «Гомін».</sub>

На Горосі бачу таке, але мені здається, що це значення сюди не пасує.

> [ПЕТЛЮВАТИЙ](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96)
>
> 1. Те саме, що петлеподібний.
> 2. Непрямий, який утворює петлі (у 2 знач. ); звивистий. Петлювата стежка.
>    <sub>Великий тлумачний словник (ВТС) сучасної української мови Видавництво "Перун", 2005</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спетлювати - дрібно змолоти. А прикметник, утворений від цього "петльований".
На Горосі ці слова є тільки у варіанті написання з И замість Е.

[ПИТЛЮВА́ТИ](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96)
Молоти і просівати борошно особливого, дрібного помолу. Приклади
Приїхала попадя до млина питлювати. (із журн.)
* Образно. – Ти питлюєш язиком, як у млині... (В. Стефаник)

[ПИТЛЬО́ВАНИЙ](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)
Дієпр. пас. до питлюва́ти. Приклади
Зате ж і Борух не знав міри своїм витребенькам, де було шиє. Давай йому і нового горшка, і свіжих яєць, і меду, і коржів з питльованого борошна. (І. Нечуй-Левицький)
Хліб був чорний, разовий, .. часто-густо між зуби попадався вістяк, але Гринуньо не зважав на те. Навіть не погадав, що може бути кращий, питльований книш, або калач. (Б. Лепкий)